# Using beautiful soup inside a loop to search for urls

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a python script that goes onto the website https://www.premierleague.com/players, takes a list of football player names from a spreadsheet I have (400+ footballer names), and inside a loop, iteratively searches for the link to each football player's page. For example : https://www.premierleague.com/players/4040/Benik-Afobe/overview.

*The final bit of the script is commented out as I have finalised that yet, but for context of what I'm eventually going to get to: it will take this list of urls that I will have obtained, and iteratively search for each players link to the player image, and append it to a list.*

I managed to get it to work for an individual player (Benik Afobe), but since adding the 'players_list' and trying a loop, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Liam/Documents/GitHub/Football_Scraping/fantast_pl_images.py", line 33, in <module>
    player_link = soup.find('a', href=re.compile('%s'))['href'] %player
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to get my loop working?

The Repo of my project can be found here: https://github.com/leej11/Football_Scraping

```
# Import the Libraries that I need
import urllib3
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

# Specify the URL
url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players'
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
response = http.request('GET', url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})


#Parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

#Importing the list of players I want to scrape the image of
players_list = pd.read_csv('epl_players_anki_clean.csv')

#Test that it's pulling all of the players names correctly
print(players_list.iloc[:,0])
print (type(players_list))

#Convert the pandas dataframe to a list of strings, with each item being the string of a player name
list_of_players = players_list['name'].values.tolist()
print(list_of_players)

#Setup an empty list to append the player links to
player_link_list = []

#Loop over the list of player names, and search for the player url and append it to the player_link_list
for player in players_list:
    player_link = soup.find('a', href=re.compile('%s'))['href'] %player
    print(player_link)
    player_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com' + '%s' %player_link
    print(player_url)
    player_link_list.append(player_url)



##### The final step
#####  To be worked on in a bit, basically take the list of links and loop over it pulling out the player image links and appending them to a list
#####
# url2 = player_url
# http2 = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
# response2 = http2.request('GET', url2, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
# soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.data, "html.parser")
# player_img = str(soup2.find("img", {'alt':'Benik Afobe'})['data-player'])
# print(player_img)
#
# photo_link = 'http://platform-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/' + '%s' %player_img + '.png'
# print(photo_link)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of `epl_players_anki_clean.csv`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 hey just added the link to my github repo with it in. Forgot to do that sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Premier League's player listing is dynamic, meaning that a browser script is loading additional players as the user scrolls down. Thus, using `requests` or `urllib` to find all the players will not work. Therefore, you will have to use a browser manipulation tool called `selenium`:

Install:

`pip install selenium`:

Then, install the proper binding for the webbrowser you are using:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers

```
import re
import selenium
import time
import csv
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/driver')#substitute Chrome with browser you are using
driver.get('https://www.premierleague.com/players')
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
  driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  if new_height == last_height:
     break
  last_height = new_height

time.sleep(10)
players = re.findall('www\.premierleague\.com/players/(.*?)/(.*?)/overview', driver.page_source)
csv_filedata = list(csv.reader(open('epl_players_anki_clean.csv')))
player_dict = {re.sub('-', ' ', b):(a, b) for a, b in players}
new_rows = [[csv_filedata[0]]+['url']]+[a+['https://www.premierleague.com/players/{}/{}/overview'.format(*player_dict[a[0]])] for a in csv_filedata]
with open('players.csv', 'a') as f:
   write = csv.writer(f)
   write.writerows(new_rows)
```

`player_dict` stores the following (truncated data):

Output:

```
{u'Asmir Begovic': [u'2537', u'Asmir-Begovic'], u'Ragnar Klavan': [u'15608', u'Ragnar-Klavan'], u'Eddie Nketiah': [u'14451', u'Eddie-Nketiah'], u'Mohamed Salah': [u'5178', u'Mohamed-Salah'], u'Jos\xe9 Holebas': [u'5713', u'Jos\xe9-Holebas'], u'Christian Eriksen': [u'4845', u'Christian-Eriksen'], u'Kurt Zouma': [u'5175', u'Kurt-Zouma'], u'Gareth Barry': [u'1308', u'Gareth-Barry'], u'Diego Costa': [u'4941', u'Diego-Costa'], u'Sam McQueen': [u'9649', u'Sam-McQueen'], u'Roque Mesa': [u'22575', u'Roque-Mesa'], u'Siem de Jong': [u'4885', u'Siem-de-Jong'], u'Lazar Markovic': [u'5078', u'Lazar-Markovic'], u'Adam Federici': [u'3182', u'Adam-Federici'], u'Dean Marney': [u'2359', u'Dean-Marney'], u'Nathan Broadhead': [u'14636', u'Nathan-Broadhead'], u'Alex Pritchard': [u'4433', u'Alex-Pritchard'], u'Matthew Pennington': [u'9895', u'Matthew-Pennington'], u'Tomas Kalas': [u'4101', u'Tomas-Kalas'], u'Nathan Ak\xe9': [u'4499', u'Nathan-Ak\xe9'], u'Mathias Normann': [u'23556', u'Mathias-Normann'], u'Grzegorz Krychowiak': [u'12735', u'Grzegorz-Krychowiak'], u'Wojciech Szczesny': [u'3543', u'Wojciech-Szczesny'], u'Charlie Adam': [u'4081', u'Charlie-Adam'], u'Marko Grujic': [u'13985', u'Marko-Grujic'], u'Harry Maguire': [u'9566', u'Harry-Maguire'], u'Isaiah Brown': [u'4674', u'Isaiah-Brown'], u'Matz Sels': [u'16723', u'Matz-Sels'], u'Leighton Baines': [u'3030', u'Leighton-Baines'], u'Marouane Fellaini': [u'3604', u'Marouane-Fellaini'], u'Jairo Riedewald': [u'4878', u'Jairo-Riedewald'], u'Glenn Murray': [u'4772', u'Glenn-Murray'], u'Tom Cadman': [u'14547', u'Tom-Cadman'], u'Ryan Shawcross': [u'3158', u'Ryan-Shawcross'], u"N'Golo Kant\xe9": [u'13492', u"N'Golo-Kant\xe9"], u'Aaron Ramsey': [u'3548', u'Aaron-Ramsey'], u'Stephen Kingsley': [u'10517', u'Stephen-Kingsley'], u'Eliaquim Mangala': [u'5334', u'Eliaquim-Mangala'], u'Josh Tymon': [u'13477', u'Josh-Tymon'], u'Mohamed Diam\xe9': [u'3982', u'Mohamed-Diam\xe9'], u'Sofiane Boufal': [u'12584', u'Sofiane-Boufal'], u'Nya Kirby': [u'15134', u'Nya-Kirby'], u'Max Melbourne': [u'15160', u'Max-Melbourne'], u'Marcin Bulka': [u'23695', u'Marcin-Bulka'], u'Rub\xe9n Sobrino': [u'16608', u'Rub\xe9n-Sobrino'], u'Tareiq Holmes Dennis': [u'8340', u'Tareiq-Holmes-Dennis'], u'Martin Cranie': [u'2559', u'Martin-Cranie'], u'Connor Mahoney': [u'7985', u'Connor-Mahoney'], u'Jamaal Lascelles': [u'9257', u'Jamaal-Lascelles'], u'Phil Foden': [u'14805', u'Phil-Foden'], u'Arijanet Muric': [u'19911', u'Arijanet-Muric'], u'Sadio Man\xe9': [u'6519', u'Sadio-Man\xe9'], u"Aiden O'Neill": [u'20095', u"Aiden-O'Neill"], u'Steve Cook': [u'8045', u'Steve-Cook'], u'Samuel Shashoua': [u'15142', u'Samuel-Shashoua'], u'Kyle Bartley': [u'3312', u'Kyle-Bartley'], u'Bojan': [u'4898', u'Bojan'], u'Jason Puncheon': [u'4084', u'Jason-Puncheon'], u'Damien Delaney': [u'1911', u'Damien-Delaney'], u'Steven Defour': [u'5345', u'Steven-Defour'], u'Christian Walton': [u'8159', u'Christian-Walton'], u'Timothy Fosu Mensah': [u'13561', u'Timothy-Fosu-Mensah'], u'Michael Keane': [u'4333', u'Michael-Keane'], u'Levi Lumeka': [u'14170', u'Levi-Lumeka'], u'Chancel Mbemba': [u'5850', u'Chancel-Mbemba'], u'Brice Dja Dj\xe9dj\xe9': [u'5577', u'Brice-Dja-Dj\xe9dj\xe9'], u'Vurnon Anita': [u'4550', u'Vurnon-Anita'], u'Jefferson Montero': [u'10518', u'Jefferson-Montero'], u'Toby Alderweireld': [u'4916', u'Toby-Alderweireld'], u'Dominic Calvert Lewin': [u'9576', u'Dominic-Calvert-Lewin'], u'Brad Jackson': [u'13246', u'Brad-Jackson'], u'James McArthur': [u'4224', u'James-McArthur'], u'Mat Ryan': [u'12192', u'Mat-Ryan'], u'Bartosz Kapustka': [u'19679', u'Bartosz-Kapustka'], u'Robert Snodgrass': [u'4558', u'Robert-Snodgrass'], u'Jonathan Leko': [u'13866', u'Jonathan-Leko'], u'Harry Arter': [u'8050', u'Harry-Arter'], u'Connor Goldson': [u'9634', u'Connor-Goldson'], u'Shaun Hobson': [u'21691', u'Shaun-Hobson'], u'Ayoze P\xe9rez': [u'10487', u'Ayoze-P\xe9rez'], u'Marc Pugh': [u'8049', u'Marc-Pugh'], u'Luciano Narsingh': [u'7122', u'Luciano-Narsingh'], u'Michael Folivi': [u'14298', u'Michael-Folivi'], u'Adri\xe1n': [u'4852', u'Adri\xe1n'], u'Mason Holgate': [u'10564', u'Mason-Holgate'], u'Joy Mukena': [u'15118', u'Joy-Mukena'], u"Lewis O'Brien": [u'24353', u"Lewis-O'Brien"], u'Javier Manquillo': [u'4918', u'Javier-Manquillo'], u"Dara O'Shea": [u'15154', u"Dara-O'Shea"], u"Clinton N'Jie": [u'6903', u"Clinton-N'Jie"], u'Yoan Gouffran': [u'4554', u'Yoan-Gouffran'], u'Michael Carrick': [u'1634', u'Michael-Carrick'], u'Moha': [u'13778', u'Moha'], u'Michy Batshuayi': [u'7450', u'Michy-Batshuayi'], u'Nathaniel Chalobah': [u'4105', u'Nathaniel-Chalobah'], u'Ryan Inniss': [u'4760', u'Ryan-Inniss'], u'Etienne Capoue': [u'4843', u'Etienne-Capoue'], u'Badou Ndiaye': [u'20538', u'Badou-Ndiaye'], u'Alexandre Lacazette': [u'6899', u'Alexandre-Lacazette'], u'Charlie Rowan': [u'14285', u'Charlie-Rowan'], u'Nathan Ferguson': [u'23976', u'Nathan-Ferguson'], u'Anthony Georgiou': [u'15146', u'Anthony-Georgiou'], u'Dujon Sterling': [u'14572', u'Dujon-Sterling'], u'Axel Tuanzebe': [u'13559', u'Axel-Tuanzebe'], u'Emre Can': [u'5001', u'Emre-Can'], u'Sam Surridge': [u'13195', u'Sam-Surridge'], u'Ryan Kent': [u'13509', u'Ryan-Kent'], u'Marc Albrighton': [u'3564', u'Marc-Albrighton'], u'Joe Williams': [u'10454', u'Joe-Williams'], u'Tom Heaton': [u'2933', u'Tom-Heaton'], u'Danny Rose': [u'3507', u'Danny-Rose'], u'Nathan Redmond': [u'3811', u'Nathan-Redmond'], u'Chicharito': [u'4161', u'Chicharito'], u'Dean Whitehead': [u'2980', u'Dean-Whitehead'], u'M.J. Williams': [u'10464', u'M.J.-Williams'], u'Harry Winks': [u'7488', u'Harry-Winks'], u'Josh Sims': [u'15374', u'Josh-Sims'], u'Charlie Gilmour': [u'14453', u'Charlie-Gilmour'], u'Aaron Wan Bissaka': [u'14164', u'Aaron-Wan-Bissaka'], u'Marc Muniesa': [u'4822', u'Marc-Muniesa'], u'Beni Baningime': [u'14623', u'Beni-Baningime'], u'Demarai Gray': [u'7946', u'Demarai-Gray'], u'Junior Stanislas': [u'3766', u'Junior-Stanislas'], u'Liam Rosenior': [u'2464', u'Liam-Rosenior'], u'Nathaniel Clyne': [u'4604', u'Nathaniel-Clyne'], u'Kamil Grabara': [u'19909', u'Kamil-Grabara'], u'Anthony Martial': [u'11272', u'Anthony-Martial'], u'Ben Foster': [u'2932', u'Ben-Foster'], u'Laurent Depoitre': [u'16747', u'Laurent-Depoitre'], u'Mike van der Hoorn': [u'4877', u'Mike-van-der-Hoorn'], u'Didier Ndong': [u'20708', u'Didier-Ndong'], u'Jordon Mutch': [u'3333', u'Jordon-Mutch'], u'Harry Kane': [u'3960', u'Harry-Kane'], u'Fernandinho': [u'4804', u'Fernandinho'], u'Riyad Mahrez': [u'8983', u'Riyad-Mahrez'], u'Kleton Perntreou': [u'14144', u'Kleton-Perntreou'], u'Dion Henry': [u'10855', u'Dion-Henry'], u'Kelechi Iheanacho': [u'13554', u'Kelechi-Iheanacho'], u'Salom\xf3n Rond\xf3n': [u'6030', u'Salom\xf3n-Rond\xf3n'], u'Ryan Allsop': [u'3732', u'Ryan-Allsop'], u'Erik Pieters': [u'4821', u'Erik-Pieters'], u'Willy Caballero': [u'10466', u'Willy-Caballero'], u'Claudio Yacob': [u'4673', u'Claudio-Yacob'], u'Craig Dawson': [u'4198', u'Craig-Dawson'], u'Jayson Molumby': [u'15293', u'Jayson-Molumby'], u'Lucas Leiva': [u'3137', u'Lucas-Leiva'], u'Martin Dubravka': [u'6451', u'Martin-Dubravka'], u'Bruno': [u'8162', u'Bruno'], u'Sam Johnstone': [u'4331', u'Sam-Johnstone'], u'Jes\xfas G\xe1mez': [u'11070', u'Jes\xfas-G\xe1mez'], u'Tomer Hemed': [u'13234', u'Tomer-Hemed'], u'Victor Moses': [u'3983', u'Victor-Moses'], u'Vincent Janssen': [u'15481', u'Vincent-Janssen'], u'Lo\xefc Remy': [u'4572', u'Lo\xefc-Remy'], u'Craig Cathcart': [u'3160', u'Craig-Cathcart'], u'Leroy Fer': [u'4810', u'Leroy-Fer'], u"Kieran O'Hara": [u'13584', u"Kieran-O'Hara"], u'Ola Aina': [u'10439', u'Ola-Aina'], u'Winston Reid': [u'4209', u'Winston-Reid'], u'Jose Baxter': [u'3608', u'Jose-Baxter'], u'Michael Obafemi': [u'21532', u'Michael-Obafemi'], u'Bruno Martins Indi': [u'11177', u'Bruno-Martins-Indi'], u'Laurent Koscielny': [u'4030', u'Laurent-Koscielny'], u'Borja Bast\xf3n': [u'16622', u'Borja-Bast\xf3n'], u'Daryl Janmaat': [u'10480', u'Daryl-Janmaat'], u'Freddy Woodman': [u'10479', u'Freddy-Woodman'], u'Jordy Hiwula Mayifuila': [u'10949', u'Jordy-Hiwula-Mayifuila'], u'Raphael Spiegel': [u'4679', u'Raphael-Spiegel'], u'Anthony Knockaert': [u'8982', u'Anthony-Knockaert'], u'Harry Lewis': [u'14982', u'Harry-Lewis'], u'Henrikh Mkhitaryan': [u'5102', u'Henrikh-Mkhitaryan'], u'Santiago Cazorla': [u'4477', u'Santiago-Cazorla'], u'Sean Scannell': [u'8887', u'Sean-Scannell'], u'Christian Atsu': [u'4859', u'Christian-Atsu'], u'Pascal Gro\xdf': [u'22542', u'Pascal-Gro\xdf'], u'Charlie Austin': [u'9468', u'Charlie-Austin'], u'Sam Byram': [u'8945', u'Sam-Byram'], u'Daniel Sturridge': [u'3154', u'Daniel-Sturridge'], u'Ga\xebtan Bong': [u'5721', u'Ga\xebtan-Bong'], u'Martin Kelly': [u'3644', u'Martin-Kelly'], u'Jack Payne': [u'9664', u'Jack-Payne'], u'Michel Vorm': [u'4398', u'Michel-Vorm'], u'Oriol Romeu': [u'4286', u'Oriol-Romeu'], u'Philip Billing': [u'8882', u'Philip-Billing'], u'Matthew Lowton': [u'4487', u'Matthew-Lowton'], u'Wayne Hennessey': [u'2569', u'Wayne-Hennessey'], u'Geoff Cameron': [u'4636', u'Geoff-Cameron'], u'Tammy Abraham': [u'13286', u'Tammy-Abraham'], u'Elvis Manu': [u'12374', u'Elvis-Manu'], u'Marvin Zeegelaar': [u'10123', u'Marvin-Zeegelaar'], u'Jordy Clasie': [u'12365', u'Jordy-Clasie'], u'Wayne Routledge': [u'2681', u'Wayne-Routledge'], u'Tom Anderson': [u'8234', u'Tom-Anderson'], u'Stephen Duke McKenna': [u'23738', u'Stephen-Duke-McKenna'], u'Harry Charsley': [u'14632', u'Harry-Charsley'], u'Erik Lamela': [u'4842', u'Erik-Lamela'], u'Elias Kachunga': [u'19611', u'Elias-Kachunga'], u'Molla Wagu\xe9': [u'21730', u'Molla-Wagu\xe9'], u'Ilkay G\xfcndogan': [u'5101', u'Ilkay-G\xfcndogan'], u'Ashley Williams': [u'4403', u'Ashley-Williams'], u'Lewis Grabban': [u'8055', u'Lewis-Grabban'], u'Seamus Coleman': [u'3600', u'Seamus-Coleman'], u'Jason Denayer': [u'11002', u'Jason-Denayer'], u'Jack Wilshere': [u'3547', u'Jack-Wilshere'], u'Calum Chambers': [u'4620', u'Calum-Chambers'], u'Samir Nasri': [u'3546', u'Samir-Nasri'], u'Alexis S\xe1nchez': [u'4973', u'Alexis-S\xe1nchez'], u'Kyle Walker': [u'3955', u'Kyle-Walker'], u'Martin Olsson': [u'2867', u'Martin-Olsson'], u'Modou Barrow': [u'10520', u'Modou-Barrow'], u'Robbie Brady': [u'4158', u'Robbie-Brady'], u'Tom Davies': [u'13389', u'Tom-Davies'], u'Fraser Forster': [u'3170', u'Fraser-Forster'], u'Francis Coquelin': [u'3549', u'Francis-Coquelin'], u'Matt Targett': [u'4815', u'Matt-Targett'], u'Davy Klaassen': [u'4886', u'Davy-Klaassen'], u"Stefan O'Connor": [u'10425', u"Stefan-O'Connor"], u'Fraser Hornby': [u'23744', u'Fraser-Hornby'], u'Tim Krul': [u'3169', u'Tim-Krul'], u'Ryan Hill': [u'21858', u'Ryan-Hill'], u'J\xfcrgen Locadia': [u'7124', u'J\xfcrgen-Locadia'], u'Ki Sung yueng': [u'4656', u'Ki-Sung-yueng'], u'Leon Britton': [u'2152', u'Leon-Britton'], u'Mesut \xd6zil': [u'4714', u'Mesut-\xd6zil'], u'Alex Denny': [u'14643', u'Alex-Denny'], u'Nemanja Matic': [u'3861', u'Nemanja-Matic'], u'Ryan Fraser': [u'8052', u'Ryan-Fraser'], u'Julian Speroni': [u'2664', u'Julian-Speroni'], u'Joel Campbell': [u'4254', u'Joel-Campbell'], u'Robert Elliot': [u'2214', u'Robert-Elliot'], u'Tosin Adarabioyo': [u'13549', u'Tosin-Adarabioyo'], u'Jack Colback': [u'3713', u'Jack-Colback'], u'Soufyan Ahannach': [u'24695', u'Soufyan-Ahannach'], u'Aaron Connolly': [u'21653', u'Aaron-Connolly'], u'Yasin Ben El Mhanni': [u'20879', u'Yasin-Ben-El-Mhanni'], u'Kazenga Lua Lua': [u'3173', u'Kazenga-Lua-Lua'], u'Ben Chilwell': [u'13491', u'Ben-Chilwell'], u'Aaron Ramsdale': [u'13703', u'Aaron-Ramsdale']}
```